# VoiceOver on iOS app does not read comment content

Tags: support, bug, ios-app

Using VoiceOver (iPhone 4s, iOS 7.1.2) in the StackExchange app, it works fairly well, except the content of comments (when viewing an answer or question) is not announced. It will just say the number of votes that comment has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was [fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267285/235711) in 1.4.1 released on December 11.  Unfortunately we have dropped support for iOS 7 so the change will not be available unless you update to iOS 8 or later.

Comment: New bug: Support for iOS 7 dropped :(

Comment: @AL Unfortunately that's [status-declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257390/will-the-official-stack-exchange-app-become-compatible-with-older-versions-of-io).  I can tell you that later versions of iOS 8 ran great on my 4s and I think 9 was only an improvement.